# Why do we have $X=O_p(n^{\alpha})$, then $X=o_p(n^{\alpha+1/2})$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question about notations $O_p$ and $o_p$ (definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation). If a random variables $X=O_p(n^{1/2})$, why do we also have $X=o_p(n)$? Similarly, if $X=O_p(n^{\alpha})$, then $X=o_p(n^{\alpha+1/2})$?

Comment: We can use that $\frac{X}{n}=\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me base answer on Yvonne M. Bishop, Stephen E. Fienberg, Paul W. Holland - Discrete Multivariate Analysis_ Theory and Practice -Springer (2007), pages 475-476.

Definition for $X=O_p(n^{1/2})$ gives, that for $\forall \eta >0, \exists K $ for which $P\left\lbrace \left |\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right| \leqslant K\right \rbrace \geqslant 1- \eta$. Last inequality is same with $P\left\lbrace \left |\frac{X}{n}\right| \leqslant K\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right \rbrace \geqslant 1- \eta$ and from here, as $K\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$, we obtain definition for $X=o_p(n)$ i.e. for $\forall \eta, \varepsilon >0,  $ helds $P\left\lbrace \left |\frac{X}{n}\right| < \varepsilon \right \rbrace \geqslant 1- \eta$.

Similarly we can manage second question.

Comment: How about the inverse? If we have $X=o_p(1)$, do we have $X=O_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: No. For example $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ is in little $o_p$, but as $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}n^{\frac{1}{6}}$, then it cannot be in $O_p(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: So for claim: if $X=O_p(n^{\alpha})$, then $X=o_p(n^{\alpha+1/2})$? Here $\alpha>0$? For instance, if $X=O_p(n^{-1/2})$, it is not $X=o_p(1)$?